# Opening a PDF in Firefox 4 on OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, pdf

So I used to use this: http://code.google.com/p/firefox-mac-pdf/ but it was only for FF3.  I've looked through the extensions via the Add-on manager and I can't seem to find this or something similar for FF 4.

Anyone know of anything out there that will work?

I'm running FF4 on **OS X** 10.6.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the Firefox PDF Plugin to work with firefox 4 by following the instructions at
http://code.google.com/p/firefox-mac-pdf/issues/detail?id=182&q=FF4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary

It has the unfortunate side effect of forcing you to run FF4 in 32-bit mode, which may be a problem for some other extensions (for instance, I believe 1Password now requires 64-bit support).

Basically, there are several problems which broke PDF support on FF4:

- Firefox PDF Plugin relies on some 32-bit libraries. Since FF4 runs in 64-bit mode be default, this prevents a straightforward update to the plugin. The instructions above contain a beta version of the PDF Plugin, but I'm sure work is progressing on an official 64-bit solution.
- The Adobe Reader X plugin (for mac) only works with Safari, so this can't be used with FF4.

Comment: i wish i could give more up votes! awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Since Firefox 4 is so new, the creators of the extension may not had time to update it for FF4.

Comment: Yes...because the 259 days between initial beta release an the final version wasn't enough time to (re)develop their product.

Answer (score 0):

Last I tried, Adobe's own [Acrobat Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) worked as a plugin to display PDFs in the browser.

Comment: I do not suggest that anyone uses Acrobat Reader. The new version "X" has caused nothing but headaches for many people. A great alternative is Foxit Reader (they make great plugins too with out being bulky!). Foxit Reader can be found (free) at the following link: http://www.filehippo.com/download_foxit/

Comment: @David - really? I haven't had any issues personally :)

Comment: If you would like to know of an example @warren... Adobe Reader X completely cripples MS Office's PDF functionality, such as being able to embed a PDF in an excel document (don't ask why). I tried uninstalling Adobe Reader X, and installing Foxit, in which the problem went away. (coincidence? I think not...) There was also an issues with Instant search when Outlook is running with administrator permissions, and there was an issue with accessing certain files because they were in use (Yes I tried diagnosing this too). All of these issues disappeared when Adobe Reader X was uninstalled.

Comment: Looks like they don't have an OS X version...unless I am missing something

Comment: O_o Wow... @Jason... I know they had one... I am going to look for a legit link for you to download it from, or a very good alternative, of which I cannot remember at the moment.

Comment: I would use Skim or Previewer (Mac's default PDF viewer) @Jason. Sorry for the confusion. I could have sworn that they had a Mac version.

Comment: @warren - Acrobat reader only installs a plugin for Safari, not FF.

Comment: @David - Apple Preview works for PDFs it just does not have a browser plugin - it requires you to download the PDF then open it.  I'll take a look at Skim

Comment: @David - No go on Skim either - it does not have a browser plugin

Comment: @Jason- sorry... Those are all of the BIG PDF viewers for Apple. I hate to say this, but I think you are SOL with all of the help I have to offer.

Comment: @David...thanks for the effort - I'll keep looking